# why need to use NSObject?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

i am confused about that should i need to used `NSObject` to swift3 . if so please guide me also is it best practice to used `NSNumber`

```
class App: NSObject {

        var id: NSNumber?
        var name: String?
        var category: String?
        var imageName: String?
        var price: NSNumber?

        var screenshots: [String]?
        var desc: String?
        var appInformation: AnyObject?

       // override func setValue(_ value: Any?, forKey key: String) {
       //     if key == "description" {
       //         self.desc = value as? String
       //     } else {
       //         super.setValue(value, forKey: key)
       //     }
       // }

    }
```

Note : *could you tell me please why need to use NSObject ? what is the advantage ?*

Comment: It has to be `NSObject` to override function `setValue(_:forKey:)`

Comment: @Desdenova update my question !   could you tell me please why need to use NSObject ? what is the advantage ?

Comment: I don't understand your question after your comment out. You don't need to use `NSObject`, you don't even need a class. A struct  can hold those as well.

Comment: @cristanlika, basically if you don't want to expose your type to Objective C code or to do anything concerning Objective C, you don't need `NSObject` at all.

Comment: @cristanlika NSObject is the super class of all the classes of Objective C where you are free to pass any type of class object, whereas in Swift this is taken in a more advance way using `AnyObject` protocol as i mentioned in my ans have a look.

Comment: NSObject add ability to swift classes to behave as Objective-C objects.

Answer (score 4):

**NSObject class:**

This class is the root class of most Objective-C class hierarchies, from which subclasses inherit a basic interface to the runtime system and the ability to behave as Objective-C objects. [(source)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/nsobject).

**AnyObject protocol**: its a implicit confirmation of any object.

You use AnyObject when you need the flexibility of an untyped object or when you use bridged Objective-C methods and properties that return an untyped result. AnyObject can be used as the concrete type for an instance of any class, class type, or class-only protocol.

AnyObject can also be used as the concrete type for an instance of a type that bridges to an Objective-C class.

```
let s: AnyObject = "This is a bridged string." as NSString
print(s is NSString)
// Prints "true"

let v: AnyObject = 100 as NSNumber
print(type(of: v))
// Prints "__NSCFNumber"
```

The flexible behavior of the AnyObject protocol is similar to Objective-C’s id type. For this reason, imported Objective-C types frequently use AnyObject as the type for properties, method parameters, and return values. [(source)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/anyobject)

So you can use `NSNumber` variable as `AnyObject` which can be later type cast implicitly accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You're overriding a super class method:

```
override func setValue(_ value: Any?, forKey key: String) { }
```

So, if your class doesn't extends `NSObject` class, how could overrides its super class method?

You could not extend `NSObject` class, but you'll have to remove `override` keyword from code since `setValue` would become a method of your custom class. If you do it, you'll not be able to call `super.setValue(value, forKey: key)` obviously.

Comment: thanks i update my question  . could you check that please

Comment: You've commented `setValue` method, what should i check?

Comment: please guide me also is it best practice to used NSNumber

Comment: You're simply defining `price` as `NSNumber` optional variable. If this variable could be nil, it looks good.

Comment: could you tell me please why need to use NSObject ? what is the advantage ?

Comment: If your class inherits from `NSObject` class, you'll have the advantage to call `NSObject` class methods or override them to customize the default behaviour for your custom class. Your class will automatically conform to protocols like `NSObjectProtocol`, `Equatable` ecc.. since `NSObject` class already conforms to those protocols

Answer (score 0):

I've been re-learning a lot of core swift concepts, so I'm adding this answer because I think in gets at what is (actually) being asked.

---

"I'm looking at this code, and why should I use:

`class App: NSObject {`

instead of

`class App: {`

???"

---

One way to answer:

When you are writing your own class, you should only add other classes to the declaration if you have a "good reason".

That is: you want to subclass that class because you get something, like its properties or methods or protocols.

For example, we often take the behavior of `UIView` for granted, which is actually defined as:

`@MainActor class UIView : UIResponder`

A lot of what `UIView` is doing for us is often "coming from" `UIResponder`.

If Apple, hadn't done, this views would still be really nice looking to the user, but your app would probably be very boring if views were not interactive (and keep in mind,`UIView` is the superclass of many other `UIKit` classes. Apple does not list the subclasses in their class documentation, so this is not made clear.)

Going back to your code, using `NSObject` is needed if you want to `override func setValue`.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1418139-setvalue

Whether or not you *should* do this for the original situation described, I think depends on the details of what you were working on…